# python - SQL Select Conditional statements in python

Tags: python, sql, r

This is my R piece of code but i want to do the same thing in python, as i am new in it having problems to write the correct code can anybody guide me how to write this is python. I have already made connections of database and also tried simple queries but here i am struggling

```
sql_command <- "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Id) FROM \"Bowlers\";"
total<-as.numeric(dbGetQuery(con, sql_command))
data<-setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol=8, 
nrow=total)),c("Name","Wkts","Ave","Econ","SR","WicketTaker","totalovers",
"Matches"))

for (i in 1:total){
sql_command <- paste("SELECT * FROM \"Bowlers\" where Id = ", i ,";", 
sep="")
p<-dbGetQuery(con, sql_command)
p[is.na(p)] <- 0
data$Name[i] = p$bowler[1]
}
```

after this which works fine how should i proceed to write the loop code:

```
with engine.connect() as con:
rs=con.execute('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM "Bowlers"')
for row in rs:
print (row)
```

Comment: Show us what you tried and where it's failing.

Comment: i have edited you can check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `format` method for strings in python to achieve it.
I am using postgresql, but your connection should be similar. Something like:

**connect to *test* database:**

```
import psycopg2 
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='your_user' host='your_host' password='your_password'")

cur = con.cursor()                     # cursor method may differ for your connection
```

**loop over your id's:**

```
for i in range(1,total+1):
    sql_command = 'SELECT * FROM "Bowlers" WHERE id = {}'.format(i)

    cur.execute(sql_command)           # execute and fetchall method may differ
    rows = cur.fetchall()              # check for your connection

    print ("output first row for id = {}".format(i))
    print (rows[0])                    # sanity check, printing first row for ids 
    print('\n')                        # rows is a list of tuples     
                                       # you can convert them into numpy arrays
```

Comment: thank you so much, also now i have two datafarmes 'p' and 'data' and i have to transfer the selected column values of p(for every iteration) into dataframe 'data'. how should i do this?

Comment: as per your r code above: `data$Name[i] = p$bowler[1]`. you can do something like this in python: `data['Name'].iloc[i] = p['bowler'].iloc[1]`.